# How do I create a circle cut out from top of a div along with the shadow for the div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to achieve this similar cutout effect can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using an SVG to draw the shape

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
body {
  background-color: theme(colors.slate.800);
}
</style>

<svg height=200 width=500 viewBox="0 0 500 200" class=m-5>
  <path d="M1 200V21a20 20 90 0120-20H180a20 20 90 0120 20 50 50 180 00100 0 20 20 90 0120-20H479a20 20 90 0120 20V200" stroke=2 class="stroke-slate-100 fill-slate-900"/>
</svg>
```